# Convert 2018-04-10T04:00:00.000Z string to DateTime

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I convert this string format `2020-04-12T00:00:00+05:30` to datetime format using SQL Server?

Comment: Is that december 4th, or april 12th?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Your title and question have difference date formats?

Comment: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.

Comment: I mean specifically, what should "2020-04-12T00:00:00+05:30" turn into? If I understand correctly +05:30 is a timezone difference, so what timezone do you want to convert it to?

Comment: This example will return the value as UTC ('2020-04-11 18:30:00.000'): `SELECT CAST(CAST('2020-04-12T00:00:00+05:30' AS datetimeoffset) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS datetime);`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `convert()` :

```
select convert(datetime2, '2020-04-12T00:00:00+05:30')
```

Comment: That gives (for me) "2020-04-12 00:00:00" - seems to have lost the 5:30?

Answer (score 0):

As your value has a timezone, you want to use [`datetimeoffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetimeoffset(0), '2020-04-12T00:00:00+05:30');
```

Other data types, like `datetime` and `datetime2` are timezone agnostic, so will effectively "truncate" that part from the date and time value.